# Do you duchen in an Avel's house?

Tags: halacha, birchas-kohanim, tefillah-betzibbur

In Israel where they Duchen daily, do you Duchen in a minyan in an Avel's house during the week of Shiva?
If yes, do the Aveilim leave the room during duchening?
If there is no Kohen does the Chazzan read the Birchas Kohanim in the repitition of the Shmoneh Esrai?

Comment: See [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/64403) (R' Shmuel Eliyahu), [here](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9C/) (R' Tzvi Yanir), [here](https://www.ykr.org.il/question/13650/) (R' Adir Cohen), and [here](https://gushetzioncemetery.org.il/הלכות-ומנהגים-בבית-האבל) (in the name of R' Ovadya Yosef). See also [Halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Practices_in_the_Mourner%27s_House#Davening). Re. a kohein in mourning, see Sh"A OC 128:43.

Comment: See also [here](https://dinonline.org/2017/06/28/birchas-kohanim-beis-havel/).